# Отправить в запросе curl SOAP запрос чистым xml

Tags: curl, perl

Выполняю SOAP Запрос следующей командой:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
    system( '"D:\\FOLDER\\curl\\src\\curl.exe"',
         "-s",
         "-o",
         "result.xml",
         "-X",
         "POST",
         "-H",
         "Authorization: Basic xxxx=",
         "-H",
         "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8",
         "-H",
         "SOAPAction:",
         "-d",
    "\@D:\\FOLDER\\request.xml",
         "http://xxx:81/yyy/zzz");
```

Этот запрос работает, но я хочу посылать запрос не файлом, а чистым xml внутри запроса, как это сделать?
Пробовал ключи --data-raw, --data-urlencode, сыпет различными ошибками.

Ниже пример с LWP::UserAgent он с теми же параметрами пишит ошибку refuse connection

```
my $message = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:urn=\"urn:xxxxxxxx\">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:GetItemByGTIN>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <urn:GTIN>123123123123</urn:GTIN>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:lang>RU</urn:lang>
         <urn:showMeta>0</urn:showMeta>
         <urn:noCache></urn:noCache>
         <urn:loadChangeVersion></urn:loadChangeVersion>
         <urn:noCascade></urn:noCascade>
         <urn:noGepir></urn:noGepir>
      </urn:GetItemByGTIN>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>";
my $userAgent=LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $request=HTTP::Request->new(POST =>'http://xxxx:81/yyyy/zzzz');
$request->header(SOAPAction => '""');
$request->header(Authorization => 'Basic xxxx');
$request->content($message);
$request->content_type("text/xml; charset=utf-8");
my $response = $userAgent->request($request);
print $response->as_string;
```

Comment: А зачем использовать внешнюю программу curl. Раз уж делаете в perl, используйте библиотеки языка. например LWP::UserAgent

Comment: Добавил мой код на LWP, он у меня не заработал.

Comment: хм. connection refused означает только одно - на порту 81 сервера xxxx нет никакого сервиса. т.е. URL не правильный.

Comment: Через Curl работает

Comment: Разобрался с LWP я подключен через прокси, в LWP нужно добавить строку $userAgent->env_proxy; чтобы использовать системную проксю.